# Validation Error on SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following Action method inside my Asp.net mvc web application:-

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(SDJoin sdj, FormCollection formValues)
{
    Try
    {
        //code goes here
        repository.InsertOrUpdateSD(sdj.StorageDevice, User.Identity.Name, assetid);
        repository.Save();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //code goes here
    }
    PopulateViewBagData();
    return View(sdj);
}
```

which calls the following method:-

```
public void InsertOrUpdateSD(TMSStorageDevice sd, string username, long assetid)
{
    var resource = entities.Resources.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(a => a.RESOURCEID == assetid);
    if (sd.TMSStorageDeviceID == default(int))
    {
        // New entity
        int technologyypeID = GetTechnologyTypeID("Storage Device");
        Technology technology = new Technology
        {
            IsDeleted = true,
            IsCompleted = false,
            TypeID = technologyypeID,
            Tag = "SD" + GetTagMaximumeNumber2(technologyypeID).ToString(),
            StartDate = DateTime.Now,
            IT360ID = assetid
        };

        InsertOrUpdateTechnology(technology);
        Save();

        sd.TMSStorageDeviceID = technology.TechnologyID;
        tms.TMSStorageDevices.Add(sd);
    }
}
```

My model class is as follow:-

```
public partial class TMSStorageDevice
{
    public int TMSStorageDeviceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> size { get; set; }
    public int RackID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }

    public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }
    public virtual TMSRack TMSRack { get; set; }
}
```

but if i call the Create action method i will get the following exception:-

```
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException was caught
  HResult=-2146232032
  Message=Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at TMS.Models.Repository.Save() in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS\TMS\Models\Repository.cs:line 1926
       at TMS.Controllers.StorageDeviceController.Create(SDJoin sdj, FormCollection formValues) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS\TMS\Controllers\StorageDeviceController.cs:line 160
  InnerException:
```

Can anyone advice what is wrong, as i double check my code and every thing should work fine ?
Thanks

Comment: Did you "see the `EntityValidationErrors` property for details"?

Comment: it shows one error with the folloiwng description "
System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationResult}"

Comment: And looking at the `ValidationErrors` property should tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: there is no ValidationErros section..

Comment: Catch the object `DbEntityValidationException` within your method `InsertOrUpdateSD`.  That should help you find the validation error.

Comment: Also, what's your `Technology` class?  That may be where the validation error lies.

Comment: You've got 2 calls to `Save()` which doesn't look right - one in the `Create` method and another in the `InsertOrUpdateSD` method

Comment: but i am following the same approach on other model classes ()two .Save methods, as this is the requirement for my system , and the Create process is working well for these model classes.

Comment: i catch the DbEntityValidationException , and it shows the folloiwng    
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at TMS.Controllers.StorageDeviceController.Create(SDJoin sdj, FormCollection formValues) in c:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TMS\TMS\Controllers\StorageDeviceController.cs:line 218
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

You haven't shown the `Save()` method but if you can add code like this to it you'll get an exception that contains all the details you're looking for

```
try
{
    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
{
    Exception raise = dbEx;
    foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", 
                validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                validationError.ErrorMessage);
            // raise a new exception nesting
            // the current instance as InnerException
            raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
        }
    }
    throw raise;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , using you above code i got the following user friendly error message "TMS.Models.TMSStorageDevice:The Name field is required.". and now i fix the error. but i am not sure why i did not get the same error description by default !!

Comment: Thanks bro. saved me a hell lot of time today. Wouldn't have been easy without your answer

Comment: I don't usually write comment just for say thank you, but I will make an exception this time. Thank you very much ! You saved me from a big trouble :) @qujck

Comment: I second what @KorayDurudogan says. This was immensely helpful.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Literally just used this for the second time!

Comment: Exceptional answer !! Great work otherwise i wouldn't be able to find the bug in thousand years !! Thumbs Up

Comment: Where is the Exception messages visible in Visual Studio? I can't see them being thrown after using this.

Answer (score 8):

I know the question is old now, but I hope someone finds this useful, too.

1. Most likely (and indeed, judging by your comments) the **error was that your variable doesn't pass Model validation.**
2. The other way to see the errors you couldn't see (**without changing the code**) is to look at the exception using the QuickWatch window. The problem is that 'View Details' window that you can open from exception tooltip doesn't show EntityValidationErrors. And without a catch block you don't have any exception variable you can look at in QuickWatch. Luckily, QuickWatch has PseudoVariables. 
   **So, using "$exception" pseudovariable you can easily take a look at the current unhandled exception in QuickWatch window.** (Please, see screenshots below)
   [Exception Details window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UyBK.png) and 
   [QuickWatch window with $exception pseudovariable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwJiE.png)

Comment: this idea get .Solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old post but this approach can be more fruitful!

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878739/updating-one-entity-with-one-context-and-inserting-a-new-with-another-context)

Try something like this

```
        try
        {
            pcontext.SaveChanges();
        }
       catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {             
             Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException ex)
        {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }
        catch (System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException ex)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }

        catch (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException ex) //DbContext
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            throw;
        }
```