# Entity Framework - Issues in DbContextTransaction.Rollback()

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, rollback

I connected the database using **`Entity Framework`**. I Implemented a Contact Repository to Save the Contact Information (Sample Repository). In the Said Class file, I declared a `static property` for handling `DBEntities` (i.e., `BLabsEntities`) namely "`Context`" and also declared a `static property` for `DbContextTransaction`.

In the following code I added a try catch block to handle Exceptions of Entity Framework in the `SaveContact()` Repository method. I Initiated a `transaction` before starting the Save Contact process in the above said method, then I added a exceptional data into the database table `dbo.Contact` as per my thought it thrown the `exception`. In the Catch block I'm initiating the `Rollback` process of the said transaction and I'm trying to insert the Exception message in the `ErrorLog Table`, but the Context property holds the Contact information even-though the Rollback process executed. **So, it throwing Exception in the catch block once again while on trying to insert the record in the `dbo.ErrorLog Table`**. I added a debugging snapshot for your reference.

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EF_Sample
{
    public class ContactRepository
    {
        private static BLabsEntities _context;
        private static DbContextTransaction _dbTransaction;

        protected static BLabsEntities Context
        {
            get { return _context ?? (_context = new BLabsEntities()); }
        }

        protected static DbContextTransaction DBTransaction
        {
            get { return _dbTransaction; }
            set { _dbTransaction = value; }
        }

        public void SaveContact(Contact contact = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (contact == null)
                {
                    contact = new Contact()
                    {
                        FirstName = null,
                        LastName = null
                    };
                }


                BeginTransaction();
                Context.Contacts.Add(contact);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommitTransaction(false);

                BeginTransaction();
                ErrorLog error = new ErrorLog()
                {
                    Message = ex.Message
                };

                Context.ErrorLogs.Add(error);

                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
            finally
            {
                CommitTransaction();
            }
        }

        private void BeginTransaction()
        {
            DBTransaction = Context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        }

        private void CommitTransaction(bool flag = true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (flag)
                {
                    DBTransaction.Commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    DBTransaction.Rollback();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", Ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging Snapshot:

[image]

Exception in `try Block`: Explicitly Created Exception by Code

[image]

Exception in `Catch Block`: Failure of `Rollback` operation

[image]

Database Table Structures:

[image]

Kindly assist me how to do the `Rollback` operation successfully to **clear the Context Changes**.

Comment: What exception exactly you get?(I see screen). You get this error when you try add null values, but your db columns cannot be null (not null, lastname,firstname exactly). Also Your repository is little strange. Consider implementing Repository pattern, with generic class and methods.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki - Obviously. Here I explicitly constructing a Contact object with value `NULL` to get the exception. Because in my real time implementation, I faced the same issue. So... Please guide me, in this scenario I need to `Rollback` the transaction and log the `Exception Message` in the `dbo.ErrorLog` table

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19520022/validation-error-on-savechanges Here you have  how get details of this exception, when you call `SaveChanges()`. Use it and update question.

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki - Yes. In my real implementation I'm updating more than 100 tables in a single call, So I created the Context as a static property. Once all the UPSERT process done, then finally I'm calling the `Context.SaveChanges()`. In this process if I got any exception, I need to rollback the entire `UPSERT`. Here I illustrated a simple exception. My issue is `Rollback` Failure not an Exception.

Comment: Ok, what if you use `Context.Dispose()`  and create context again instead `DBTransaction.Rollback(); `?  or reload single entity `Context.Entry(entity).Reload();` _Reloads the entity from the database overwriting any property values with values from the database_. These all changes stay in context when you try insert `ErrorLog`.

Comment: Just don't use a static context. That's the root of all troubles.

Answer (score 4):

The actual answer might be more simple:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/327

The explicit call to dbContextTransaction.Rollback() is in most cases unnecessary, because disposing the transaction at the end of the using block will take care of rolling back.

> If an error of sufficient severity occurs in SQL Server, the
>   transaction will get automatically rolled back, and the call to
>   dbContextTransaction.Rollback() in the catch block will actually fail.